# Map with bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I'm using map to iterate throug a list of elements, what I want is to have 4 elements per row. This is my render part of the class:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Card List</h1>

        {this.props.items ? this.props.items.map((item) =>
          <div class="cardSection">
            <Row className="show-grid">
                <Card name={item.name} imgGold={item.imgGold}  />
            </Row>
          </div>

        ) : <div>Loading!</div>}

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want 4 Card components per row using xs={4} md={4}

Comment: i didnt get what is your problem my friend ???

Comment: Use the second parameter of the `map` function (that is the index) to count. Create / close a row each 4 items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
const items = [
  { name: "1" },
  { name: "2" },
  { name: "3" },
  { name: "4" },
  { name: "5" },
  { name: "6" },
  { name: "7" },
  { name: "8" },
  { name: "9" },
  { name: "10" },
  { name: "11" },
];

const App = () => {
  const result = items.map((x,i) => {
      return i % 4 === 0 ? items.slice(i, i+4) : null;
  }).filter(x => x != null);

  return (
    <div>
      {result.map((result, index) => {
        return (<section key={index}>
          {result.map(item => <span>{item.name}</span>)}
        </section>);
       })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
span {
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

This will group your item array into groups of 4. You can even make it accept any number you want.

You can then iterate and render each of them in groups of 4.

Please make sure you run the snippet so you can see it working.

Comment: Does this break the key issue for the individual items in the section?  i.e.   The keys will remain the same regardless of whether the section contents have changed or not.

Comment: @billjamesdev The code I've presented yes but you can always use index of the map or even better if the items have a specific id you can give them that id.